# Simplifying an inequality: $4x(x-2) \lt 2(2x-1)(x-3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, factoring

I have: $$4x(x-2) \lt 2(2x-1)(x-3)$$ For the last part, do I multiply both things in $()$ by two then solve them like I normally would? If I solve them and then multiply will it work the same? Is that an appropriate plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply rearrange the inequality to find the $x$ satisfying said inequality. For instance,
\begin{align*}
4x(x-2) &< 2(2x-1)(x-3) \\
4x^2-8x &< 4x^2-14x+6 \\
6x &< 6 \\
x &< 1.
\end{align*}
Since all of our steps are reversible, the inequality is satisfied by those $x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x(x-2) \lt2(2x-1)(x-3)$$
$$2x^2 - 4x \lt 2x^2-6x-x+3$$
$$2x^2\lt2x^2-3x+3$$
$$0\lt-3x+3$$
$$-3\lt-3x$$
$$\text{Multiplying by }-1\text{ reverses inequality}$$
$$3\gt 3x$$
$$1\gt x$$

Comment: $-7<-7x \implies x<-1$.

Comment: LHS of 2nd line should be $2x^2 - 4x$

Comment: @IanF1 typos corrected

Comment: @user170039 Typos corrected, apologies